# python-get the degree of network nodes with networkx

Tags: python, networking, nodes, networkx

I want to use NetworkX function to get the degree distribution plot of all the nodes, and then draw a boxplot.

But the plot is not show and have a error below:

> `x = all_degrees.count(i)`
>
> `AttributeError: 'DegreeView' object has no attribute 'count'`

How to solve this problem?

mac OS 10.14.5 (18F132)
python 3.7

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_deg_dist(G):
    all_degrees = nx.degree(G)

    unique_degrees = [v for k, v in all_degrees]
    count_of_degrees = []

    for i in unique_degrees:
        x = all_degrees.count(i)
        count_of_degrees.append(x)

    plt.plot(unique_degrees, count_of_degrees)
    plt.show()

G = nx.read_gml("/Users/kate/Desktop/karate_club/karate.gml")


plot_deg_dist(G)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that `all_degrees` is `DegreeView` iterable -- *not* a `list` -- so it doesn't have the built-in count method. (In addition, `unique_degrees` is not actually going to be unique, since you can have the same value appear multiple times.)

**Fixing the main issue**

I think the simplest way to fix your issue is to redefine `all_degrees` like so (and update `unique_degrees` accordingly):

```
all_degrees = [ v for _, v in nx.degree(G) ]
unique_degrees = sorted(set(all_degrees))
```

This will yield the following plot (note that it is just a line plot):
[image: degrees plot]

**Getting the boxplot**

You can also take advantage of the [`matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) to do all the heavy lifting for you. Then, all you need to do in `plot_deg_dist` is get the list of all degrees and call the `boxplot` function:

```
all_degrees = [ v for _, v in nx.degree(G) ]
plt.boxplot(all_degrees)
plt.show()
```

[image: degrees box]

Comment: I redefined as you said but it comes following errors: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: @kate10: see the updated answer. You need to change `unique_degrees`, too.